# rails acts_as_list position auto increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the acts_as_list gem but when creating new Object the position should automatic increase in size and order position ASC.

LessonPage Model

```
class LessonPage < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_list :scope => 'lesson_id = #{lesson_id}'
    default_scope order('position ASC')
end
```

Select

```
SELECT "lesson_pages".* FROM "lesson_pages" ORDER BY position ASC, "lesson_pages".id desc
```

Insert - first

```
INSERT INTO "lesson_pages" ("created_at", "lesson_id", "position", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:55:27 CEST +02:00], ["lesson_id", 2], ["position", 1], ["updated_at", Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:55:27 CEST +02:00]]
```

Second

```
INSERT INTO "lesson_pages" ("created_at", "lesson_id", "position", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:57:15 CEST +02:00], ["lesson_id", 2], ["position", 2], ["updated_at", Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:57:15 CEST +02:00]]
```

Third

```
INSERT INTO "lesson_pages" ("created_at", "lesson_id", "position", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:58:13 CEST +02:00], ["lesson_id", 2], ["position", 2], ["updated_at", Sun, 16 Oct 2011 11:58:13 CEST +02:00]]
```

Here it fails, because position should be 3 and not 2. How do I fix this?
thanks!!

Comment: what version of acts_as_list are you using? I think it was fixed by this commit (https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/commit/f233643018ad9a2791bba0cf6dd48ff90633230e) UPDATE: Oh, I see. There is no release after this commit. I think you should use the code from github.

Comment: You are an angel! It works correct from the :git repo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/commit/f233643018ad9a2791bba0cf6dd48ff90633230e), but there is no release after this fix. I think you should use the code from github.

use this:

```
gem 'acts_as_list', :git => 'https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list.git'
```

Comment: This gem uses new hash style that is not supported by old ruby 1.8.7. So I had to use this commit's code (that was listed in your comment for question) as monkey patch. Was very helpful. Thank you.